# Mysql process taking all the memory

Tags: mysql, centos5

When I checked my process on VPS, I can see 18 instance of mysql running.  What could be wrong?

```
1780 mysql     15   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.51 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1782 mysql     19   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1783 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1784 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1785 mysql     15   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1788 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:01.65 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1789 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:01.36 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1790 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.22 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1791 mysql     15   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.02 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1792 mysql     15   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.04 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 1796 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:01.77 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 3283 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:02.01 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 3284 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:01.75 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
29973 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.45 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
29974 mysql     17   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:01.50 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
29976 mysql     17   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.75 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
29978 mysql     18   0  876M  142M  6744 S  0.0  8.1  0:00.57 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Open a `mysql` client, and enter `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` at the prompt, and paste us that output.

Comment: Is this causing a *problem*?  Even "obvious" things like a high load average are nothing to worry about unless they actually cause a problem such as "web pages load slowly" or "connections time out".  It is, however, still worth trying to understand what's going on, even if you don't have an actual problem.

Comment: Are they using more memory than MySQL is configured to use?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening.

MySQL has a bunch of processes and is waiting for something to do. Notice how the columns are `0.0`% CPU and `8.1`% memory. That 8.1% is just the shared about MySQL needs to run, but it isn't really doing anything since it has zero percent CPU usage.

This can also be confirmed by the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, which shows no-one is connected (so no queries are being run).

Comment: http://snipt.org/vQff8 Here is the Show Prcesslist.  Server Monitor App says my RAM is completely used. (1 GB)

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com - Linux likes to use all your RAM to make your server faster (so it's not just idle and a waste of money).

Comment: Thanks.  free -m 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1751       1115        635          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:       1115        635
Swap:            0          0          0